# Oracle ODP does not close connections of killed applications

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I´m using ADO.NET to access Oracle 11 database. This driver is using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll client dll.

If I execute a long update instruction and kill the application before this instruction ends, the connection remains opened until the end of the instruction.

ex.:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=myoraserver;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password";

conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
conn.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

cmd.Connection = conn;

OracleTransaction txn = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
try
{
    cmd.CommandText = "update foo set bar = 1";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    txn.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message    =  " + ex.Message);
    txn.Rollback();
}
```

There is a way to close this connection immediately after kill my app?

There is a configuration in the driver or connection string for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to dispose conn and cmd, with a using statement

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(oradb)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: It can´t be an application issue due the fact that connection keeps opened after kill the application.

Answer (score 1):

[`sqlnet.expire_time`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_connect_time_idle_expire_timeout.htm) may be what you want, although it does not kill the connection immediately:

> The sqlnet.expire_time parameter is used to set a time interval, in
>   minutes, to determine how often a probe should be sent verifying that
>   client/server connections are active. If you need to ensure that
>   connections are not left open indefinitely (or up to the time set by
>   operating system-specific parameters), you should set a value that is
>   greater than 0. This protects the system from connections left open
>   due to an abnormal client termination.
>
> When the probe detects a terminated connection or a connection no
>   longer in use, it signals an error, causing the server process to
>   exit. This setting is intended for use on the database server side of
>   the connection, which usually handles multiple connections at any one
>   time. Limitations on using this terminated (dead) connection detection
>   feature are:
>
> - sqlnet.expire_time cannot be used on bequeathed connections.
> - The SQL*Net expire_time probe packet will generate additional network
>     traffic that may downgrade the network's performance, depending on the
>     number of connections.
> - Depending on the operating system that is in use, additional server
>     processing may need to be performed to distinguish the connection
>     probe from other events that occur. This overhead for detection of
>     probe events can result in downgraded network performance.
>
> ### Turning-on expire_time
>
> To set up these advanced features, simply edit your sqlnet.ora file. 
>   If you are a beginner, follow this procedure:
>
> Start the Oracle Network Manager GUI.
>
> In the GUI navigator pane, expand the icons Local > Profile.
>
> From the list on the right hand pane, select General.
>
> Click on the Advanced tab.
>
> Next, enter the values for the fields or options you want to set.
>
> When you are finished, choose File > Save Network Configuration to
>   write your changes to the sqlnet.ora file.

Comment: I changed this file like you said, restart my test, but the connection remains active after kill app.

Comment: Even after wait for the configured time, the connection remains active.

Comment: Could the test still be using a pooled connection? Why do you need to do this anyway?

Comment: I update my connection string with Pooling=false, but no luck. My customer complains me about open connections after kill some long running reports.